# A little clue for some basic HTML parsing with BSoup 4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm totally new at this, but been trying to parse some HTML with BeautifulSoup for 2 days without any real, good results.
One time I manage to remove all HTML and just keep text as I want it, but only get 1 result on the whole table I'm parsing, and an other time I get everything I want, but just can't seem to strip all the HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("PlusGrosCAVerif.htm"))


raisonsociale = soup.find('td', {'class' : 'verif_col1'})

for noms in raisonsociale:
    listenom = raisonsociale.get_text()
    print(listenom)
```

HTML looks like this :

```
   <table id="verif_hitparade_donnees">
                    <tr id="verif_meslistes_thead">
                        <th class="verif_col1">Raison sociale</th>
                        <th class="verif_col2">CP</th>
                        <th class="verif_col3">Ville</th>
                                                    <th class="verif_col5">C.A.</th>
                    </tr>

                        <tr class="verif_result_tr_opaq2">
                            <td class="verif_col1"><a href="/societe/M-H-C-S-509553459/">M H C S</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col2"><a href="/societe/M-H-C-S-509553459/">51200</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col3"><a href="/societe/M-H-C-S-509553459/">EPERNAY</a></td>
                                                            <td class="verif_col5"><a href="/societe/M-H-C-S-509553459/">1 472 239 977&nbsp;&euro;</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="verif_result_tr_opaq">
                            <td class="verif_col1"><a href="/societe/VIVESCIA-302715966/">VIVESCIA</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col2"><a href="/societe/VIVESCIA-302715966/">51100</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col3"><a href="/societe/VIVESCIA-302715966/">REIMS</a></td>
                                                            <td class="verif_col5"><a href="/societe/VIVESCIA-302715966/">1 277 349 946&nbsp;&euro;</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="verif_result_tr_opaq2">
                            <td class="verif_col1"><a href="/societe/SOC-COOP-APPROVISIONNEMENT-PARIS-EST-301986154/">SOC COOP APPROVISIONNEMENT PARIS EST</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col2"><a href="/societe/SOC-COOP-APPROVISIONNEMENT-PARIS-EST-301986154/">51520</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col3"><a href="/societe/SOC-COOP-APPROVISIONNEMENT-PARIS-EST-301986154/">SAINT MARTIN SUR LE PRE</a></td>
                                                            <td class="verif_col5"><a href="/societe/SOC-COOP-APPROVISIONNEMENT-PARIS-EST-301986154/">1 249 176 407&nbsp;&euro;</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="verif_result_tr_opaq">
                            <td class="verif_col1"><a href="/societe/ARCELORMITTAL-DISTRI-SOLUTIONS-FRANCE-469500961/">ARCELORMITTAL DISTRI SOLUTIONS FRANCE</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col2"><a href="/societe/ARCELORMITTAL-DISTRI-SOLUTIONS-FRANCE-469500961/">51100</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col3"><a href="/societe/ARCELORMITTAL-DISTRI-SOLUTIONS-FRANCE-469500961/">REIMS</a></td>
                                                            <td class="verif_col5"><a href="/societe/ARCELORMITTAL-DISTRI-SOLUTIONS-FRANCE-469500961/">586 085 818&nbsp;&euro;</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="verif_result_tr_opaq2">
                            <td class="verif_col1"><a href="/societe/SEVEAL-757803689/">SEVEAL</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col2"><a href="/societe/SEVEAL-757803689/">51100</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col3"><a href="/societe/SEVEAL-757803689/">REIMS</a></td>
                                                            <td class="verif_col5"><a href="/societe/SEVEAL-757803689/">480 141 491&nbsp;&euro;</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="verif_result_tr_opaq">
                            <td class="verif_col1"><a href="/societe/ACOLYANCE-381960491/">ACOLYANCE</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col2"><a href="/societe/ACOLYANCE-381960491/">51100</a></td>
                            <td class="verif_col3"><a href="/societe/ACOLYANCE-381960491/">REIMS</a></td>
                                                            <td class="verif_col5"><a href="/societe/ACOLYANCE-381960491/">462 996 287&nbsp;&euro;</a></td>
                        </tr>
```

... and goes on for quite a while.

What I wanted to do was parse the td classes "verif_col" 1, 2, 3 and 5, so I could put them in a CSV file, so I first tried to get the names (verif_col1), strip them of any html around. With the code above, I only get the first name (MHCS), and then the script stops.

I've tried findAll, but I can't get it to work with a get_text() method. I've thought about findNext() and such, but to no results.

Any thoughts for a lost and clueless newbie ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `find`, use `find_all`:

```
raisonsociale = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'verif_col1'})
```

And to have the text, get the `text` attribute:

```
for noms in raisonsociale:
    print noms.text
```

C'est tout! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I've already tried using find_all, but when I do, I get this error : "AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'".
I tried toying around with contents() instead of get_text(), too, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to select every `1`, `2`, `3` and `5` of the class name and save each one in an array to print it at the end, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 
import re
import itertools as it

tds = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

for td in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': re.compile(r'verif_col\d')}):
    tds.append(td.string)

for i in range(len(tds) // 4): 
    print(','.join(it.islice(tds, i*4, 4*(i+1))))
```

You can run it like:

```
python3 script.py xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
M H C S,51200,EPERNAY,1 472 239 977 €
VIVESCIA,51100,REIMS,1 277 349 946 €
SOC COOP APPROVISIONNEMENT PARIS EST,51520,SAINT MARTIN SUR LE PRE,1 249 176 407 €
ARCELORMITTAL DISTRI SOLUTIONS FRANCE,51100,REIMS,586 085 818 €
SEVEAL,51100,REIMS,480 141 491 €
ACOLYANCE,51100,REIMS,462 996 287 €
```